# Linear Algebra. Proof with eigenvectors and orthogonal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. Consider $v$ an eigenvector of $A$ associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$, and $w$ an eigenvector of $A^T$ associated to the eigenvalue $\alpha$. Show that if $\lambda\neq\alpha$ then $v$ and $w$ are orthogonal.

Hello, I have a few doubts about this exercise and would like a way to do this proof. Thanks

Comment: This is not true. Probably there's something given that you haven't told us...

Answer (score 2):

Hint : there are two ways to write $w^T A v$ :
\begin{align*}
w^TAv &= w^T (Av)\\
&= (A^T w)^Tv
\end{align*}

Comment: You might as well complete the proof since there’s only one step left.